# Java app communicatin with a .NET application

Tags: c#, java

I've a design question.

I want two programs, one is written in c# and the second one in Java, to communicate over TCP/IP.
As part of the communication protocol between the two programs I want to send packets containing fields that are .NET types(TimeSpan for example). Is there an easy way for the Java app side to process this kind of packets or should I keep those packets basic data types based only?

Answer (score 0):

You could always marshall the object to XML, JSON, etc... that both sides could load up. Assuming TimeSpan can be placed into a string that is parsable or other primitive types, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any webservice feature like [wcf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx). make sure you use *basicHttpBinding* for maximum compatibility. You can also use [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/).